# Azure PaaS local setup

Tags: azure, paas

I am going to use Azure SQL (V12) for my production environment.

I want similar kind of setup in my Local Laptop without connecting cloud environment.
What is best version available freely with Azure SQL which ensure me that there will not be any compatibility issue in schema replication and data migration?

Or any other way to handle this for local setup.

Comment: your laptop will be faster as it's local and not shared resource. For development purposes, you could try Azure SQL in a serverless mode.

Comment: For free, the closest you will get is SQL Server Developer Edition. However, they are not the same product, just very similar and compatible. Your question is too broad to be answered as SQL Server and Azure SQL are big products with a vast number of features.

Comment: Thanks. My question is simple here. Which SQL server version I need to have locally so that If I deploy over Azure SQL PaaS then there will be no any compatibility issue OR modification needed.

Comment: Then the answer is there is no product that meets your requirements,